# How to fire React.ChangeEvent from radio button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is one of my radio buttons:

```
<input
    type="radio"
    value="0"
    id="0"
    name="salary"
    checked={salaryRange === "0"}     // Side question: is this the way to handle the active button?
    onChange={() => handleChange}     // Round brackets here seem unnecessary
/>;
0 - 1.0;
```

And this is my handleChange. Currently, it doesn't fire at all.

```
    function handleChange(
        e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
        range: string
    ) {
        console.log("changed radio button");
    }
```

I'm not getting any TS errors. Can anyone help?

Comment: You're arrow function is not calling the `handleChange` function. Just do `onChange={handleChange}`, or if you really want/need the arrow function, use `onChange={() => handleChange()}`.

Comment: This threw up a TS error. It was fixed by removing the second argument (range: string) from the handleChange call.

Thanks so much!

Comment: right idea @BrianThompson but that won't work if you actually need the event argument. You'd have to do `onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, something)}`, where `something` is the "range" argument. I've no idea how you get that because I don't understand what the OP is trying to do with this.

Comment: @RobinZigmond You're right, didn't pay close enough attention to their handler. They really shouldn't need the arrow function version anyway though. I didn't pay close enough attention to catch my misuse of *you're* either.. Yikes.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the handleChange function ref.

change `onChange={() => handleChange}`

to `onChange={handleChange}` or to `onChange={(thatsMySweetEvent) => handleChange(thatsMySweetEvent)}`

Comment: This threw up a TS error. It was fixed by removing the second argument (range: string) from the handleChange call. Thanks so much!